# What are some alternatives for "nurturing bosom"?

Tags: phrase-requests

Consider this sentence:

> "Are you prepared to leave the nurturing bosom of [business-name]'s help and support staff?"

I'm looking for something that is a little more professional yet still conveys a compelling warning.

Context:

This is part of an advice column warning readers to think twice before they customize a product and lose technical support. Also, this advice is **not** coming from someone at the company.

Comment: Is another idiom all right? In particular I'm thinking of ["supportive atmosphere"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22supportive+atmospere%22&rlz=1C1GGGE_enUS371&oq=%22supportive+atmospere%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.5976j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22supportive+atmosphere%22&safe=active) with 600k results on Google.

Comment: If I were about to take my business elsewhere because of being dissatisfied with a company's help and support... and I would be getting this line from them as a _warning_... Well, I can speculate as to my actual reaction, but I can;t predict what I would do - it's just too shocking. But suffice it to say that I would certainly not heed the warning, and I would be leaving the mentioned bosom, whatever state it's in, in seconds flat.

Comment: That's not the purpose, @oerkelens. This is part of an advice column warning readers to think twice before they customize a product and lose technical support.

Comment: ...and the advice is not coming from someone at the company.

Comment: Ah, context is _everything_ :D

Comment: Too many good answers to choose one. I liked _safe haven_, using the converse (which has richer metaphors) and avoiding a metaphor entirely. I ended up choosing the third.

Answer (score 9):

`Security` is one possible option, not necessarily because it is a direct equivalent of `nurturing bosom`, but rather because it conveys a sense of "professionalism."

"Are you prepared to leave the *security* of [business-name]'s help and support staff?"

Comment: I like this. It reminded me of *safety net*, defined [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/safety+net) as "A guarantee, as of **professional**, physical, or financial security"

Answer (score 4):

"Are you prepared to leave the **sanctuary** of [business-name]'s help and support staff?"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the converse . . . describe the plight of those who leave your *'safe harbor'*:

- *'on your own'*
- *'out in the cold'*
- *'in the wilderness'*
- *'lost and alone'*
- *'lost at sea'*
- *'stranded'*
- *'marooned'*

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use a metaphor. I'd just say "Are you prepared to customize your own [product name] with no assistance from [business]'s help and support staff?"

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the nautical metaphor of *safe harbor*, you could use **safe haven**, which to me conveys your message with more imagery than simply *security*, but is still professional and relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with **safe harbor**. In the context of technical support, I'd say it's a more apt metaphor than a nurturing bosom anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Given the context:

*stray from the fold*

It means to leave the protected flock.

It definitely coneys all you wish to convey here.

Answer (score 0):

> "Are you prepared to leave the protecting cover of [business-name]'s help and support staff?"

or

> "Are you prepared to leave the protective sanctuary of [business-name]'s help and support staff?"

Nurturing bosom, the word **protective** or **protecting** springs to mind, at first I had thought of **protecting cover** and then **protecting culture** but on seconds thoughts I think that **sanctuary** is more appropriate than **cover** with regards to help and support staff.